# Getting Wrong Results Python

Tags: python

When i run my code i keep getting the wrong results.  I am trying to get the difference and set that as the new color for the object if both object colors are not equal.  If the two colors are equal i use that color as the new color. I dont know what im missing.

Code:

```
    class DooDad :
    _serialNumber = 1000

    def __init__(self, color, weight, value):
        self._color = color
        self._weight = weight
        self._value = value
        DooDad._serialNumber = DooDad._serialNumber + 1
        self._serialNumber = DooDad._serialNumber

    def getColor(self):
        return self._color

    def getWeight(self):
        return self._weight

    def getValue(self):
        return self._value

    def getSerialNumber(self):
        return self._serialNumber

    def __add__(self, other):
        if self._serialNumber - other._serialNumber == 1 or other._serialNumber - self._serialNumber == 1:
            newValue = self._value * other._value
        else:
            newValue = self._value + other._value

        maxWeight = max(self._weight, other._weight)
        leftColor = self._color
        return DooDad(self._color, maxWeight, newValue)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        leftColor = self._color
        rightWeight = other._weight
        minValues = min(self._value, other._value)
        return DooDad(leftColor, rightWeight, minValues)

    def __mul__(self, other):  
        maxWeight = max(self._weight, other._weight)
        avgValue = (self._value + other._value) / 2
        if self._color != other._color:
            colorNotIn = self._notInEither(self._color, other._color)
            return DooDad(colorNotIn, maxWeight, avgValue)

        return DooDad(self._color, maxWeight, avgValue)    


    def _notInEither(self, color1, color2):
        allColors = {"red", "blue", "green"}
        colors = {color1, color2}
        print(colors)
        colorNotIn = allColors.difference(colors)
        return "".join(colorNotIn)


    def __repr__(self):
        return " %s DooDad weighing %.0f grams. Value = %f points. S/N= %i" % (self._color, self._weight, self._value, self._serialNumber)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doodads = []
    doodads.append(DooDad("red",5,10))
    doodads.append(DooDad("red",8,9))
    doodads.append(DooDad("blue",20,15))
    doodads.append(DooDad("green",2,5))
    doodads.append(doodads[0] + doodads[1])
    doodads.append(doodads[2] + doodads[0])
    doodads.append(doodads[3] - doodads[1])
    doodads.append(doodads[1] - doodads[3])
    doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[1])
    doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[2])
    doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[4]) #blue but i get red
    doodads.append(doodads[3] * doodads[4]) #red but i get blue



    for doodad in doodads:
        print(doodad)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `Example[0] * Example[4]`?

Comment: its for an assignment when two objects get multiplied it will create a new object with specifications in __mul__ function

Comment: Please post your actual code. What you have posted would not work because `Example` is not iterable (you mean `doodads)` and also there is no [4] because you have only added 4 elements and list indexes are 0-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just testing your class wrong; `Example[x]` should be `doodads[x]`.

```
doodads = []
doodads.append(Example("red",5,10))
doodads.append(Example("red",8,9))
doodads.append(Example("blue",20,15))
doodads.append(Example("green",2,5))
doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[3]) #blue
doodads.append(doodads[3] * doodads[4]) #red
```

Output:

```
red  weighing 5 grams. Value = 10.000000 points. S/N= 1001
red  weighing 8 grams. Value = 9.000000 points. S/N= 1002
blue  weighing 20 grams. Value = 15.000000 points. S/N= 1003
green  weighing 2 grams. Value = 5.000000 points. S/N= 1004
blue  weighing 5 grams. Value = 7.000000 points. S/N= 1005
red  weighing 5 grams. Value = 6.000000 points. S/N= 1006
```

Comment: i was changing the names when i posting the question here that was a typo on my part but i posted full code in the question

Comment: In this line: `doodads.append(doodads[0] * doodads[4]) #blue but i get red`, we have that `doodads[0]` (which is `Example("red",5,10)`) and `doodads[4]` (which is `doodads[0] + doodads[1]`) are both red, so their product should be red too, not blue.

Comment: i want doodads[4] to be DooDad("green",2,5)

Comment: Then what you want is not `doodads[4]`, but `doodads[3]`. Remember, lists are 0-indexed.